# JSX.Elent' is not assignble to type 'ReactNode' in React Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

New to Typescript and React, I'm getting a lint error

> Type '({ Token }: { Token: string; }) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'..

```
 {ClientComponent}
```

```
const ClientComponent = ({Token}: {Token: string}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {Token ? <div>Customer exists</div> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

What is the best way to fix this error? Thank you

Comment: `{ClientComponent}` what is that? Please show where and how you use this component.

Comment: in a function return eg: return (   <div className="relative">
                  {ClientComponent}
                </div> );   -- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use components as Tags, not just by the name

Your code should be changed from

`return ( <div className="relative"> {ClientComponent} </div> )`

to

`return ( <div className="relative"> { <ClientComponent token={ tokenVar }  /> } </div> )`

Please make sure to change `tokenVar` to whatever the variable name you have your token.

Comment: Thank you, then I get the following error "Property 'Token' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ Token: any; }'"

Comment: Sorry I missed that. I've changed the answer. Please make sure to change tokenVar to whatever the variable name you have your token.

Comment: And mark the answer as the accepted answer is this solved your issue

Comment: It helped not quite solved, gives error "Cannot find name 'myVariable'."

Comment: What is `myVariable`? Where have you used it?